# Error: "read only file system" on rmdir

Tags: system, terminal, cache

I have problems with my Google Play so I tried to solve them from [this blog](http://jimmod.com/blog/2011/10/15/android-market-error-on-downloading-error-downloading-there-is-insufficient-space-on-the-device/),

> 1. You gonna need Android Terminal Simulator or equivalent terminal app. This will also require your Android rooted.
> 2. Type `su` (root permission request will be showed, you need to approve it).
> 3. Type `cd /`
> 4. Type `umount /cache`
> 5. Type `mount -o rw,remount -t rootfs rootfs /` (to set the folder access to rw – read write)
> 6. **Type `rmdir /cache` (delete cache folder)**
> 7. I personally using root explorer to do point 5-6
> 8. Type `mkdir /sdcard/cache`
> 9. Type `ln -s /sdcard/cache /cache` (to link cache folder to `/sdcard/cache` – which should have bigger partition size)

I have a problem with no. 6. I get an error that says 'read only file system'. The dir `/cache` is not read only.

How can I solve this problem and delete the folder? Or can I link the `/cache` folder without delete it?

**edit**
When I do step 5 so in step 6 it says device or resorce is busy. So according to comments in the blog post I rebooted my phone so maybe step 5 "canceled". How can I forcely do step 6  even if it busy?

Comment: Could you mention your phone model and Android version? Also, is your device rooted?

Comment: I have lenovo s8 android 4.4.2 kernel 3.4.67 special version lenovo20140914

Comment: You cannot simply delete the `/cache` dir. That's the mount point for the cache partition, residing on a *read-only* file system. If in step 6 you get the "read only" error, obviously step 5 failed. And no: you cannot "overwrite" a file or directory with a link.